# How to transfer iPad images data to a web server?

Tags: java, ios, ipad, google-app-engine

I am using google app engine and eclipse to do up the web server and capture images and images data from an iPad app, it means when the user use the iPad app to upload images and it can be save on a web server instead of saving on the iPad. So How do I do up a web service in eclipse using java and it can be link to google app engine and the google app engine can link to the iPad App? I really appreciate that someone could help. Thanks.

Comment: What kind of data? iOS applications are pretty sandboxed, so what they can "capture" is quite limited.

Comment: Google App Engine and Eclipse? That sure as heck isn't an iPad app.

Comment: You have a long way to go . Learn about ios development and then revisit this question.

Comment: @Perception: It is not unheard of for iPad apps to have a server-side component ...

Comment: @Thilo - I'm pretty sure the OP is asking questions about the iPad side of the equation, not the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up about RESTful web services. Basically make an HTTP request from your iPad app to get data from the server or put data on the server.